# Graph is not displaying

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, stock

The graphing details are being displayed (axes,labels,legend,title). But, the actual plot line is not displaying.

Here the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from TFANN import ANNR
from google.colab import files

#reads data from the file and ceates a matrix with only the dates and the prices 

stock_data = np.loadtxt('FB.csv', delimiter=",", skiprows=1, usecols=(1, 4))

#scales the data to smaller values
stock_data=scale(stock_data)

#gets the price and dates from the matrix
prices = stock_data[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1)
dates = stock_data[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)

#creates a plot of the data and then displays it
mpl.plot(dates[:, 0], prices[:, 0], label='5 Year Chart')
#
mpl.xticks(rotation=70)
mpl.xlabel("Year")
mpl.ylabel("Price")
mpl.xlim(2015,2019)
mpl.ylim(50,250)
mpl.legend()
mpl.title('Trend Analysis')

mpl.show()
```

please help

Comment: What do you see when you print `dates[:, 0]` and `prices[:, 0]`

Comment: Are you executing this code in google colab? Maybe try to add `%matplotlib inline` then

Comment: What does your data look like? Try removing your x/y limits.